# How do you get the fact that a cell of a datagridview has been modified without the cell losing focus?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview with a check box in it. The point is when the user clicks the check box I immediately want to perform an action. The problem I have is, If I process the cell click method this does not work if the user uses the keyboard.  I can tie onto the currentcelldirtystatechanged event but this is only raised the first time the cell is changed but not subsequent times. Essentially I want to act immediately and not force the user to change the cell that is currently in focus.

Comment: Could you not also use a key down event to check for when the user uses the keyboard?

Comment: Hmmm interesting I had not thought of this.. It might work, although it seems like a lot of work for something that *I* think should be simple...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [CurrentCellDirtychanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx) event and the [IsCurrentCellDirty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.iscurrentcelldirty.aspx) property.

```
// This event handler manually raises the CellValueChanged event
// by calling the CommitEdit method.
void dataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender,
    EventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a "CellEnter" event that will be raised when a cell gains focus, however that may happen. The user may not have changed anything yet, but the behavior you describe (clicking on the cell or tabbing/arrowing into it) doesn't require them to.